Linear analysis tool in Simulink not giving proper/exact transfer function?
I have a Simulink model as shown in attached snap. I am able to see its step response but i am trying to see equivalent simplified transfer function.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS-_n4YPLEo&ab_channel=krpsinfos
I have seen above Youtube video and its method(Linear Analysis Tool) is working for relatively simple systems but for advanced systems like one in attached snap, not giving fully accurate results
I know that we may be able to find equivalent simplified transfer function by writing relevant code in MATLAB script and using series and feedback commands appropriately  but isn't there any feature in MATLAB or Simulink that helps in directly converting this Simulink Model to equivalent simplified transfer function without having to write any code in MATLAB script
The model shown in snap is discussed in detail in below youtube video but does not answers my main confusion
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgtCUECmeqU&ab_channel=AaronYurkewich

I have also added snaps of original transfer function and step response of original system

I have also added snap of Linear analysis tool transfer function and step response


I may be rusty, but I think you can find the exact equivalent transfer function.
Let's define intermediate transfer function H1(s) for the electrical loop and H2(s) for the mechanical loop (see image below):

H1(s) = (1/Ls) / (1+R/Ls)
H2(s) = (1/Js) / (1+b/Js)

Then, you get the overall transfer function:
y = (H1*Kt*H2) / (1+H1*Kt*H2*Kb) * u
You would need to work a little bit to find the canonical form, but nothing to worry about.

